# How to apply a recent bug fix in jQuery

Tags: jquery, version-control, bug-tracking

There is a recent bug fix for a problem I am having in jQuery:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8209#comment:9

How can I integrate this change easily in my version of jQuery? (right now I use Google's, but I assume I would need to switch to my own).  I know only the basics of Git.

Comment: That's a bugfix for Webkit, not jQuery that you've linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the latest jquery with most recent fixes from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js.

Comment: excellent!  I'm sure I should have been able to figure that out on my own, so thanks!